# Access a specific entry in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I would like to read a specific entry in my Core Data store.

Let's say I have 20 entries, I would like to read all attributes of the entry where for example `name = john`. I would like to know all other values such as age, address etc. is there a way to access this row directly like it can be done with SQL over a query? or do I have to itherate trough all rows till I find the one with the informations I need?

Comment: Read the documentation on `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: thanks! will do right now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a problem at all. Just create `NSFetchRequest` with desired entity. And set in it predicate like this:

```
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@",name]]
```

To make more complex predicate look at [predicate programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html).

Comment: You should probably demonstrate the format string style of predicates, since it's unlikely he wants to hard code a name. i.e. `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@", name]]`